# service architecture - webservies | soa

Tags: java, web-services, architecture, soa

I would like to understand which approach suits the best to manage the below scenario.

Say for example there are 25 applications mostly in java and are web based deployed across different platforms jboss, websphere & tomcat. Each application exposes 3 -5 services and also consumes services from other applications. Most of them are synchronous and are triggered on need basis. Some of the use cases below,

1. When a patient is admitted, this sends out message to 4 -5 systems which are interested in admission detail (sync).
2. Billing system send detail to another system to calculate the discount (sync)
3. Get Patient detail by passing the id. (sync)

So if u try to represent the whole diagram in a picutre if will be like so many hardcoded static lines between each and every system.

The problems

1. No common way to find the health of each systems or web services until the user complains some thing not working.
2. Too many web services and end points to keep track off.
3. Implemented across diff standards JAX-wS, Jax-RS, due to diff application servers and containers.
4. Some messages are identical with slightly different details. Thus reusability is reduced and end up coming up with new service for each custom requirement.

What kind of solution are better suited to address the above issues ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult and common problem in large enterprises. What you could look at is integrating an [enterprise service bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus) into your firm to facilitate SOA. You could then implement adaptors for each of the systems in your ecosystem. The adaptor interfaces would be tightly controlled, documented and standardised.
There is a fairly large cost in doing this though.

As regards checking system health. You could look at using a platform such as [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/). You would need to identify some innocuous web services (a basic read for example) that could be used to determine if a given system is "Up". Nagios could then call this periodically.

Comment: Thank you Nick Ryan for ur time. Yes ESB is one option we are closely looking at. But nowadays I see lot of artical saying SOA is dead and so on and that makes me skeptical towards it. Other option I am looking at is AMQP such Rabbit MQ, also plan to migrate some of the error prone web services in to plan REST/JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need a ServiceBus it doesn't have to be a full-fledge ESB but you do need an integration and mediation point to make sure you manage the different end-point types and the different protocols without resorting to 1-1 connections.

You can look at [Fuse Mediation Hub](http://fusesource.com/products/enterprise-camel/) (based on [apache camel](http://camel.apache.org/)). Again externalizing the integration logic from the different services you have will give you more flexibility. For example it will let you migrate the different services to REST/JSON you mentioned without the need to change each of the services that depend on the services that are evolving (keep the whole thing working throughout the transition).

Regarding monitoring - you may want to consider looking at [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) it can connect to a lot of sources (the app server's logs, JMX, SNMP) and correlate events. They have a free version (for up to 500Mb of data a day)